# Prove that the set of Turing-decidable languages are closed under reversal.

Tags: formal-languages, automata, turing-machines

I.e., prove if $L$ is Turing-decidable, then $L^ℛ=\{x\in\Sigma^* | x^ℛ\in L, \text{ where }x^ℛ\text{ is the reverse of }x\}$ is Turing-decidable. I know that the statement is true, but struggling with how to prove it formally.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/136703/755

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $L$ is decidable, then we can decide $x \in L^{\mathscr{R}}$ by reversing $x$ and checking if the result is in $L$.

Comment: +1. A bit more formally, the point is that the function sending a string $x$ to its reverse is a computable function.